# Python - Run function with list item as parameter

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I want to run a list of functions, where each function should take one item from a list as parameter.

*Func1 parameter takes first list value, Func2 parameter takes second list value...and so on.*

So far, I have the following:

> main.py

```
#import the 5 python files
import sheet_1 as s1
import sheet_2 as s2
import sheet_3 as s3
import sheet_4 as s4
import sheet_5 as s5

#save the functions in a list
func_lst = [s1.func1, s2.func2, s3.func3, s4.func4, s5.func5]
```

```
#save workbook key as list
sheet_lst = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5"]
```

> sheet_1.py

```
def sheet1(n): #n param should take "Sheet1"
    print(n*2) #prints "Sheet1Sheet1"
```

> sheet_2.py

```
def sheet2(n): #n param should take "Sheet2"
    print(n*2) #prints "Sheet2Sheet2"
```

> sheet_3.py

```
def sheet3(n): #n param should take "Sheet3"
    print(n*2) #prints "Sheet3Sheet3"
```

And so on...

To make it more visual, this is how the code should look/work like:

```
#for first iteration
for item in sheet_lst:  #take "Sheet1"
for f in func_lst: #take s1.func1
        f(item) #run function with item parameter.
```

The end result of the loop would be:

```
s1.func1("Sheet1"); 
s2.func2("Sheet2"); 
s3.func3("Sheet3"); 
s4.func4("Sheet4"); 
s5.func5("Sheet5");
```

Does anyone have any clue on how to structure the loop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure of goal.  Given list of functions `func_lst` and list of sheets `wbkey`, are you trying to apply first function `func_list[0] to wbkey[0], func_list[1] to wbkey[1],...etc.`?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. 
I want to send item from list, as parameter for each function.

>>s1.func1("Sheet1"); 
>>s2.func2("Sheet2");
>>s3.func3("Sheet3"); 
>>s4.func4("Sheet4");
>>s5.func5("Sheet5");

Comment: @DarrylG I will edit the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [zip](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp)  to produce a loop like you describe

```
for wbkey, f in zip(sheet_lst, func_lst):
   f(wbkey)
```

The result of the above is:

```
s1.func1("Sheet1"); 
s2.func2("Sheet2"); 
s3.func3("Sheet3"); 
s4.func4("Sheet4"); 
s5.func5("Sheet5");
```

Comment: @DarryIG For some reason, it goes only until s4.func4. Leaving s5.func5 out.

Comment: @Raccoon_17--zip will iterate to the length of the shorter length.  Are you certain you placed 5 elements in sheet_lst and func_list?

Comment: @DarryIG I added some more items but both lists have the same number of items. 
func_lst has 10 functions and sheet_lst has also 10 items in the list.

Comment: @Raccoon_17--what do you get with: `print(list(zip(sheet_lst, func_lst))`.  It should be a list  of tuples with the first element of each tuple from sheet_list and the second from func_list.

Comment: @DarryIG It finally worked! You were right!
Thank you a lot for your help!! :)